# Beginner Java: Basic Encryption Program (Ceasar Cipher)

Tags: java

A question was given to us in our exam last week. We were asked to design a class that could be used to input a string and a number where the characters of the string move as many spaces back as the number entered.

There's two things to keep in mind. One, the case does not matter. The output can be in the same case or can be standardized. Two, if A and 2 are input, Y is what we get. The alphabets go around.

Sample Input:

> I Love Java
>
> 2

Sample Output:

> G JMTC HYTY

This is what I came up with during the exam (it was a written one so I had no way to check if it worked). When I compiled and ran it, here's what I'm getting -

Sample Input:

> I Love Java
>
> 2

Sample Output:

> G8JMTC8HYTY

I tried a few more words and so basically here's what's happening. The spaces are replaced by a number that is 10-(the

```
import java.util.*;
public class ENCRYPT
{
    static void main()
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string");        
        String a=in.nextLine();        
        a=a.toLowerCase(); 
        System.out.println("Enter the encrption value");
        int m=in.nextInt();
        String x=""; char ch;
        for(int i=0; i<a.length(); i++)
        {
            ch=a.charAt(i);
            if((int)ch-97<m)
            {
                x=x+(char)((123-m)+(int)ch-97);
            }
            else if(ch==' ')
            {
                x=x+' ';
            }
            else
            {
                x=x+(char)((int)ch-m);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(x.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want to implement Caesar Cipher...

Comment: If this question has been sufficiently answered, please mark the post that solved your problem as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark in the answer. There is no need to put "accepted" in the title of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because **(int)ch-97 < m** is **true** for space also.So it goes inside if statement.

You can solve it by placing space check first and then your code...

```
if(ch==' ')
    {
        x=x+' ';
    } else if((int)ch-97<m)
    {
        x=x+(char)((123-m)+(int)ch-97);
    }
    else
    {
        x=x+(char)((int)ch-m);
    }
```

Comment: Mark the solution as ACCEPTED if your problem is oslved.In this way ,it will help others looking for similar problem

Comment: @zwoshed Please close the thread by marking the answer as ACCEPTED if the solution helped you